# How to get time reminder before 1 hour in outlook using power automate

Tags: datetime, sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-list, power-automate-custom-connector

I have a SharePoint Online list named "Medical Appointments" having some columns including Select date [Appointment Date] with time. Now, I need to create an automated flow like whenever a user adds an item with a selection of date and time; then the particular user will get the remainder email before 1 hour, like, be ready for your appointment.[image]

Here, I didn't get any clue to solve this issue, can you provide any solution...

Comment: Use a recurrence trigger that fires every minute and compare the times in the list to see if it’s exactly an hour in the future. You just have to do the work so my advice, just start.

Comment: You can add a "Delay Until" action to wait until one hour before the appointment time and add an "Office 365 Outlook - Send an email" action to send the reminder email to the user who added the appointment.